# Calculating years since first observation in monthly time-series R in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to find a solution to calculate the years since the beginning of a monthly time-series using data.table. My dataframe looks like this:

```
library(data.table)

structure(list(Date = structure(c(8581, 8611, 8643, 8673, 8702, 
8734, 8765, 8796, 8824, 8855, 8884, 8916, 8946, 8975, 9008), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

          Date
 1: 1993-06-30
 2: 1993-07-30
 3: 1993-08-31
 4: 1993-09-30
 5: 1993-10-29
 6: 1993-11-30
 7: 1993-12-31
 8: 1994-01-31
 9: 1994-02-28
10: 1994-03-31
11: 1994-04-29
12: 1994-05-31
13: 1994-06-30
14: 1994-07-29
15: 1994-08-31
```

These are just 15 observations, but they can go up to hundreds.
I would like to create a column that calculates the years that have gone by since the beginning of the time series, like the one below. To simplify the issue, I want to start counting at 0 and add 1 every 12 months.

```
          Date  Years
 1: 1993-06-30    0
 2: 1993-07-30    0
 3: 1993-08-31    0
 4: 1993-09-30    0
 5: 1993-10-29    0
 6: 1993-11-30    0
 7: 1993-12-31    0
 8: 1994-01-31    0
 9: 1994-02-28    0    
10: 1994-03-31    0
11: 1994-04-29    0
12: 1994-05-31    0
13: 1994-06-30    1
14: 1994-07-29    1
15: 1994-08-31    1

Note that the time-series starts in June. The beginning can be any month.
```

Comment: Do you need `df1[, Years := findInterval(Date - first(Date), seq(366, length.out = 10, by = 365))]`

Comment: That does not work for me. Simply outputs 10 for every Date.

Comment: I get `df1[,  findInterval(Date - first(Date), seq(366, length.out = 10, by = 365))]#
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1`

Comment: I edited my original post, perhaps my question is more clear now. My time series has hundreds of monthly observations, perhaps that is why it caps at 10.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a placeholder.  I thought, there will be only 10 years or so difference.  You can change it to a higher number

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is a *rolling join* with a *lookup table*

```
library(data.table)
lut <- setDT(df1)[, .(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "1 year"))][
  , Years := seq_along(Date) - 1L][]
lut[df1, on = .(Date), roll = Inf]
```

> ```
>           Date Years
>  1: 1993-06-30     0
>  2: 1993-07-30     0
>  3: 1993-08-31     0
>  4: 1993-09-30     0
>  5: 1993-10-29     0
>  6: 1993-11-30     0
>  7: 1993-12-31     0
>  8: 1994-01-31     0
>  9: 1994-02-28     0
> 10: 1994-03-31     0
> 11: 1994-04-29     0
> 12: 1994-05-31     0
> 13: 1994-06-30     1
> 14: 1994-07-29     1
> 15: 1994-08-31     1
> ```

The lookup table is

```
lut
```

> ```
>          Date Years
> 1: 1993-06-30     0
> 2: 1994-06-30     1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[, years:=floor(as.numeric(Date-min(df$Date))/365.25)]
```